# driver.get multiple urls causes false test failure

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting started on a system that will contain a growing collection of single page apps and I'm looking into how to organize their ui tests to scale sanely. I'd like to write a test module per page as an exercise to verify it but I'm having some trouble with invoking driver.get() in succession.

specs/index.js

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var server = new require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer(path, {port: 4444});
var specs = [
    require('./google'), require('./bing')
];

//...

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
         .usingServer(server.address())
         .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
         .build();

test.describe('while learning webdriverjs', function() {
    test.after(function() {
        driver.quit();
    });

    specs.forEach(function(spec) {
        spec.run(driver, webdriver, test);
    });
});
```

specs/bing.js

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

function run(browser, webdriver, test) {
    test.describe('a trip to bing', function() {
        browser.get('http://www.bing.com');

        test.it('does not fail', function() {
            browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
               expect(title).to.equal('Bing');
            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports = { run: run };
```

specs/google.js

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

function run(browser, webdriver, test) {
    test.describe('a trip to google', function() {
        browser.get('http://www.google.com');

        test.it('does not fail', function() {
            browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
                expect(title).to.equal('Google');
            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports = { run: run };
```

Now running either google.js or bing.js alone runs fine, but running the two in succession returns:

```
while learning webdriverjs
    a trip to bing
      1) does not fail
    a trip to google
      ✓ does not fail


1 passing (12s)
1 failing

1) while learning webdriverjs a trip to bing does not fail me:

  + expected - actual

  +"Bing"
  -"Google"

  at <anonymous>
==== async task ====
WebDriver.getTitle()
  at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/.../node_modules/selenium-    webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:267:15)
  at webdriver.WebDriver.getTitle (/.../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:640:15)
  at /.../projects/learn-webdriver/specs/bing.js:9:11
  at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/.../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1445:20)
  at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/.../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1310:8)
  at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
==== async task ====
  at Context.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:119:12)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:194:15)
  at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:372:10)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:448:12
  at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:297:14)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:307:7
  at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:245:23)
  at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:274:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm sure driver.get() is moving faster than the specs.  I've also noticed that using done() to complete an async test isn't available in selenium-webdriver/testing (I got "undefined is not a function" when I tried).

I've also tried not using the selenium wrapped mocha globals with strange results - on my Win 7 Enterprise, all tests immediately pass, then the browser is fired up and anything that fails afterwards throws an exception; on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, all tests immediately pass and no browser instance ever loads.

I'm sure I haven't exhausted the possible ways to organize these tests so they'd run properly, but I can't see them atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke down and decided to go with [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor).

My issue was largely organizational and this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running your tests in parallel, yet you're passing through the same instance of the driver to each so they'll be sharing the browser window.

I'm not sure you're using the webdriverjs testing stuff correctly either. I've not used it myself but if there's a `test.describe(...)` I'd expect there to be a `test.it(...)`.

Take a look at [one of the test files in web driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#git%2Fjavascript%2Fnode%2Fselenium-webdriver%2Ftest) as to how they write the tests.

Comment: sharing the browser window is the general idea, otherwise a separate browser instance for each "module" will be really slow - trying to mitigate that here.  Mocha (and by proxy, selenium-webdriver/testing) can perfectly handle nested "test.describes". the expectations ("test.it") are in the modules themselves.  now you mentioned running in parallel - there may be something to that, but even the link you've mentioned does not have any reference to suite serialization nor test organization, so not sure how it helps.

Comment: I need to take back part of that statement - the tests at the link provided did show that a new driver instance is created for each spec. It's just rather innocuous looking. Also, an env object is feeding that driver instance - one that's passed in at test.suite, but it's not clear if this is applied to test.describe.  I'm still wrapping my head around this. Thanks for your input.